# Showing a screenshot in a newly created window in C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I made a program that takes a screenshot and saves it in the local folder (this worked). I deleted that part and wanted to show the newly taken screenshot in a newly created window. Everything is good, the screenshot gets taken, the window gets created but the only problem is that the window does not show the taken screenshot.

If you want to run the code in Visual Studio you have to change `Properties -> Linker -> System -> SubSystem (in Visual Studio)` from `Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)` to `Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)`

How can I show the newly taken screenshot in the newly created window?

This is the code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <windows.h>
#include <objidl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
using namespace Gdiplus;
#pragma comment (lib,"Gdiplus.lib")

int GetEncoderClsid(const WCHAR* format, CLSID* pClsid)
{
    UINT num = 0;
    UINT size = 0;
    Gdiplus::ImageCodecInfo* pImageCodecInfo = NULL;

    Gdiplus::GetImageEncodersSize(&num, &size);
    if (size == 0) {
        printf("Error: GetImageEncodersSize returned size 0\n");
        return -1;
    }

    pImageCodecInfo = (Gdiplus::ImageCodecInfo*)(malloc(size));
    if (pImageCodecInfo == NULL) {
        printf("Error: malloc failed to allocate memory for ImageCodecInfo\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (GetImageEncoders(num, size, pImageCodecInfo) != Ok) {
        printf("Error: GetImageEncoders failed\n");
        free(pImageCodecInfo);
        return -1;
    }

    for (UINT j = 0; j < num; ++j) {
        if (wcscmp(pImageCodecInfo[j].MimeType, format) == 0) {
            *pClsid = pImageCodecInfo[j].Clsid;
            free(pImageCodecInfo);
            return j;
        }
    }

    free(pImageCodecInfo);
    return -1;
}

void TakeScreenshot()
{
    // Get the dimensions of the whole desktop
    int dpi_x = GetDpiForSystem();
    int dpi_y = GetDpiForSystem();
    int width = GetSystemMetricsForDpi(SM_CXSCREEN, dpi_x);
    int height = GetSystemMetricsForDpi(SM_CYSCREEN, dpi_y);

    if (width == 0 || height == 0) {
        printf("Error: GetSystemMetrics returned invalid screen dimensions\n");
        return;
    }

    // Create a bitmap to hold the screenshot
    HDC screen_dc = GetDC(NULL);
    if (screen_dc == NULL) {
        printf("Error: GetDC failed to get a handle to the screen device context\n");
        return;
    }

    HDC mem_dc = CreateCompatibleDC(screen_dc);
    if (mem_dc == NULL) {
        printf("Error: CreateCompatibleDC failed to create a compatible device context\n");
        ReleaseDC(NULL, screen_dc);
        return;
    }

    // Create a bitmap that is scaled to the appropriate DPI
    HBITMAP bitmap = CreateBitmap(width, height, 1, GetDeviceCaps(screen_dc, BITSPIXEL), NULL);
    if (bitmap == NULL) {
        printf("Error: CreateCompatibleBitmap failed to create a compatible bitmap\n");
        DeleteDC(mem_dc);
        ReleaseDC(NULL, screen_dc);
        return;
    }

    HGDIOBJ old_bitmap = SelectObject(mem_dc, bitmap);

    // Set the DPI of the memory DC to match the system DPI
    SetGraphicsMode(mem_dc, GM_ADVANCED);
    XFORM xform;
    xform.eM11 = (FLOAT)dpi_x / 96;
    xform.eM12 = xform.eM21 = xform.eM22 = 0;
    xform.eDx = xform.eDy = 0;
    SetWorldTransform(mem_dc, &xform);

    // Copy the screen contents to the bitmap
    if (BitBlt(mem_dc, 0, 0, width, height, screen_dc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY) == 0) {
        printf("Error:BitBlt failed to copy screen contents to bitmap\n");
        return;
    }

    // Save the bitmap to a file
    Gdiplus::Bitmap image(bitmap, NULL);
    if (image.GetLastStatus() != Ok) {
        printf("Error: Bitmap constructor failed to create a Bitmap object\n");
        return;
    }

    CLSID png_clsid;
    int r = GetEncoderClsid(L"image/png", &png_clsid);
    if (r == -1)
    {
        printf("Error: unable to find image encoder for MIME type 'image/png'\n");
        return;
    }

    HWND hwnd;
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    // Define window class
    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = DefWindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.lpszClassName = L"ScreenshotWindowClass";
    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    // Create window
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        L"ScreenshotWindowClass",
        L"Screenshot",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, width, height,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if (hwnd == NULL) {
        printf("Error: CreateWindowEx failed to create window\n");
        return;
    }

    // Show screenshot in window
    HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
    Graphics graphics(hdc);
    graphics.DrawImage(&image, 0, 0, width, height);
    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);

    // Display window
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    // Wait for user to close window
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    // Clean up
    UnregisterClass(L"ScreenshotWindowClass", hInstance);


    // Clean up
    SelectObject(mem_dc, old_bitmap);
    DeleteObject(bitmap);
    DeleteDC(mem_dc);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, screen_dc);
}

int main()
{
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT dpi_awareness_context = SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext(DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_SYSTEM_AWARE);

    TakeScreenshot();

    SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext(dpi_awareness_context);

    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please select language tags matching your code. Your code is C++, not C.

Comment: `HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);` probably fails, or returns a DC with zero-sized clipping region, because you call it at the time the window is still hidden. In any case, when the window is shown, it'll be asked to paint itself, and at that point `DefWindowProc` will just fill it with the background brush specified in the window class, erasing whatever you managed to paint (if anything). You need to implement your own window procedure that handles `WM_PAINT`, at least.

Comment: Where is the part where you handle WM_PAINT and display the screenshot in the window?

Comment: You cannot reliably render window contents from the outside. You'll want to register a window class with a custom window procedure that does what you want.

Comment: @user253751 I didn't knew I needed that. I'm gonna try writing it now.

Answer (score 1):

The core issue here is the attempt to render onto a window "from the outside". Displaying window contents is difficult to do without the target window's cooperation. What you should do instead is have the window itself handle the display.

When registering a window class, the function pointer assigned to `lpfnWndProc` is what implements the window's behavior. In a simple case like this there are only two messages that need to be handled explicitly: [`WM_PAINT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/wm-paint) (responsible for rendering the client area), and [`WM_DESTROY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-destroy). The latter is required so that we can break out of the following message loop by posting a `WM_QUIT` thread message.

The following implementation also handles [`WM_CREATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-create) to enable passing the bitmap handle into [`CreateWindowEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindowexw) and storing it in per-window memory for convenient access.

*`ScreenshotWndProc`:*

```cpp
LRESULT CALLBACK ScreenshotWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (Msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE: {
        // Read `HBITMAP` from `CREATESTRUCT`
        auto const params = reinterpret_cast<CREATESTRUCT const*>(lParam)->lpCreateParams;
        auto const bitmap = reinterpret_cast<HBITMAP>(params);
        // Store the bitmap at index 0
        ::SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, 0, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(bitmap));
        // Continue window creation
        return 0;
    }

    case WM_DESTROY:
        ::PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    case WM_PAINT: {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps = {};
        HDC hdc = ::BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        // Get client size
        RECT rc = {};
        ::GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);
        auto const width = rc.right - rc.left;
        auto const height = rc.bottom - rc.top;

        // Retrieve bitmap from window
        auto const bitmap = reinterpret_cast<HBITMAP const>(::GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, 0));

        // Create a memory device context to blit from
        auto const src_dc = ::CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        auto const prev_bmp = ::SelectObject(src_dc, bitmap);

        // Blit bitmap to client area
        ::BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, width, height, src_dc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

        // Clean up memory device context
        ::SelectObject(src_dc, prev_bmp);
        ::DeleteDC(src_dc);

        ::EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        // Message has been processed
        return 0;
    }

    default:
        break;
    }

    return ::DefWindowProc(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

*Adjusted window class registration and window creation:*

```cpp
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    // Define window class
    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = ScreenshotWndProc;
    wc.cbWndExtra = sizeof(HBITMAP); // reserve memory for one `HBITMAP`
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.lpszClassName = L"ScreenshotWindowClass";
    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    // Create window
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, L"ScreenshotWindowClass", L"Screenshot", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                          CW_USEDEFAULT, width, height, NULL, NULL, hInstance, bitmap);
```

Since this design relies on the intermediate window holding a reference to the screenshot bitmap, it is important for that bitmap to no longer be selected into any device context, and also outlive the window. This requires re-arranging part of the resource management code, so here is the full sample code for reference:

```cpp
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <windows.h>

#include <objidl.h>

#include <stdio.h>

#include <gdiplus.h>
using namespace Gdiplus;
#pragma comment(lib, "Gdiplus.lib")

int GetEncoderClsid(const WCHAR* format, CLSID* pClsid)
{
    UINT num = 0;
    UINT size = 0;
    Gdiplus::ImageCodecInfo* pImageCodecInfo = NULL;

    Gdiplus::GetImageEncodersSize(&num, &size);
    if (size == 0)
    {
        printf("Error: GetImageEncodersSize returned size 0\n");
        return -1;
    }

    pImageCodecInfo = (Gdiplus::ImageCodecInfo*)(malloc(size));
    if (pImageCodecInfo == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: malloc failed to allocate memory for ImageCodecInfo\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (GetImageEncoders(num, size, pImageCodecInfo) != Ok)
    {
        printf("Error: GetImageEncoders failed\n");
        free(pImageCodecInfo);
        return -1;
    }

    for (UINT j = 0; j < num; ++j)
    {
        if (wcscmp(pImageCodecInfo[j].MimeType, format) == 0)
        {
            *pClsid = pImageCodecInfo[j].Clsid;
            free(pImageCodecInfo);
            return j;
        }
    }

    free(pImageCodecInfo);
    return -1;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK ScreenshotWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (Msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE: {
        // Read `HBITMAP` from `CREATESTRUCT`
        auto const params = reinterpret_cast<CREATESTRUCT const*>(lParam)->lpCreateParams;
        auto const bitmap = reinterpret_cast<HBITMAP>(params);
        // Store the bitmap at index 0
        ::SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, 0, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(bitmap));
        // Continue window creation
        return 0;
    }

    case WM_DESTROY:
        ::PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    case WM_PAINT: {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps = {};
        HDC hdc = ::BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        // Get client size
        RECT rc = {};
        ::GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);
        auto const width = rc.right - rc.left;
        auto const height = rc.bottom - rc.top;

        // Retrieve bitmap from window
        auto const bitmap = reinterpret_cast<HBITMAP const>(::GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, 0));

        // Create a memory device context to blit from
        auto const src_dc = ::CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        auto const prev_bmp = ::SelectObject(src_dc, bitmap);

        // Blit bitmap to client area
        ::BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, width, height, src_dc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

        // Clean up memory device context
        ::SelectObject(src_dc, prev_bmp);
        ::DeleteDC(src_dc);

        ::EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        // Message has been processed
        return 0;
    }

    default:
        break;
    }

    return ::DefWindowProc(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
}

void TakeScreenshot()
{
    // Get the dimensions of the whole desktop
    int dpi_x = GetDpiForSystem();
    int dpi_y = GetDpiForSystem();
    int width = GetSystemMetricsForDpi(SM_CXSCREEN, dpi_x);
    int height = GetSystemMetricsForDpi(SM_CYSCREEN, dpi_y);

    if (width == 0 || height == 0)
    {
        printf("Error: GetSystemMetrics returned invalid screen dimensions\n");
        return;
    }

    // Create a bitmap to hold the screenshot
    HDC screen_dc = GetDC(NULL);
    if (screen_dc == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: GetDC failed to get a handle to the screen device context\n");
        return;
    }

    HDC mem_dc = CreateCompatibleDC(screen_dc);
    if (mem_dc == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: CreateCompatibleDC failed to create a compatible device context\n");
        ReleaseDC(NULL, screen_dc);
        return;
    }

    // Create a bitmap that is scaled to the appropriate DPI
    HBITMAP bitmap = CreateBitmap(width, height, 1, GetDeviceCaps(screen_dc, BITSPIXEL), NULL);
    if (bitmap == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: CreateCompatibleBitmap failed to create a compatible bitmap\n");
        DeleteDC(mem_dc);
        ReleaseDC(NULL, screen_dc);
        return;
    }

    HGDIOBJ old_bitmap = SelectObject(mem_dc, bitmap);

    // Set the DPI of the memory DC to match the system DPI
    SetGraphicsMode(mem_dc, GM_ADVANCED);
    XFORM xform;
    xform.eM11 = (FLOAT)dpi_x / 96;
    xform.eM12 = xform.eM21 = xform.eM22 = 0;
    xform.eDx = xform.eDy = 0;
    SetWorldTransform(mem_dc, &xform);

    // Copy the screen contents to the bitmap
    if (BitBlt(mem_dc, 0, 0, width, height, screen_dc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY) == 0)
    {
        printf("Error:BitBlt failed to copy screen contents to bitmap\n");
        return;
    }

    // Select `bitmap` out of memory device context
    SelectObject(mem_dc, old_bitmap);
    // We're done with the DC's, so clean them up
    DeleteDC(mem_dc);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, screen_dc);

    // Save the bitmap to a file
    Gdiplus::Bitmap image(bitmap, NULL);
    if (image.GetLastStatus() != Ok)
    {
        printf("Error: Bitmap constructor failed to create a Bitmap object\n");
        return;
    }

    CLSID png_clsid;
    int r = GetEncoderClsid(L"image/png", &png_clsid);
    if (r == -1)
    {
        printf("Error: unable to find image encoder for MIME type 'image/png'\n");
        return;
    }

    HWND hwnd;
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    // Define window class
    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = ScreenshotWndProc;
    wc.cbWndExtra = sizeof(HBITMAP); // reserve memory for one `HBITMAP`
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.lpszClassName = L"ScreenshotWindowClass";
    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    // Create window
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, L"ScreenshotWindowClass", L"Screenshot", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                          CW_USEDEFAULT, width, height, NULL, NULL, hInstance, bitmap);

    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: CreateWindowEx failed to create window\n");
        return;
    }

    // Display window
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    // Wait for user to close window
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    // Make sure the `bitmap` lives as long the window
    DeleteObject(bitmap);

    // Clean up
    UnregisterClass(L"ScreenshotWindowClass", hInstance);
}

int main()
{
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT dpi_awareness_context = SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext(DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_SYSTEM_AWARE);

    TakeScreenshot();

    SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext(dpi_awareness_context);

    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
    return 0;
}
```

---

As an aside: The `nWidth` and `nHeight` arguments passed into `CreateWindowEx` designate the *window* size. The code suggests that what you actually want is a window with a desired *client* size. You can call [`AdjustWindowRectEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-adjustwindowrectex) to calculate the window rectangle that corresponds to a given client rectangle.

Answer (score -1):

According to [When to Draw in a Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/when-to-draw-in-a-window), It's practical to paint outside of WM_PAINT.

> If an application draws at any other time, such as from within [WinMain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-winmain)
> or during the processing of keyboard or mouse messages, it calls the
> [GetDC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winuser/nf-winuser-getdc) or [GetDCEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winuser/nf-winuser-getdcex) function to retrieve the display DC.

As @IgorTandetnik explained yesterday, probably due to the painting happens before `ShowWindow`, It's erased because of `ShowWindow` drawing with default white background. The following code works for me.

```
    // Display window
    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

    // Show screenshot in window
    HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
    Graphics graphics(hdc);
    graphics.DrawImage(&image, 0, 0, width, height);
    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
```

Comment: *"The following code works for me"* is short for saying *"I haven't been creative enough to make it fail"*. Here's a tip: Resize the window.

Comment: While that's another topic.

Comment: Providing a *sustainable* solution is not *"another topic"*. I wonder what your employers incentives are here. Get as many questions handled as possible, even if the solutions are completely useless?

Comment: Nothing. My solution is completely based on the customer's code. If the customer wants a *sustainable* code, he can refer to the [SimpleDrawing](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/7cbd99ac1d2b4a0beffbaba29ea63d024ceff700/Samples/Win7Samples/begin/LearnWin32/SimpleDrawing/cpp/main.cpp#L423) sample or ask it.

Comment: @kylewalker, have you checked my answer which I have tested working? You're drawing before the window displayed.

Comment: Stop talking folks into accepting your answer. Which, incidentally, *doesn't* work. The window class is registered with the `CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW` style. Feel invited to learn what those class styles [mean](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-class-styles).